# c++ basic classes

Tags: c++, class, subclass

Lets say i have a television class and BigTelevision class

```
class television
{
  protected:
       int a; 
  ...
}
class BigTelevision:public television
{
   private:
   int b;
...
}
```

I want to contain a collection of a mixed of television and BigTelevision, what options do i have.
I know one way is to use array but the problem with this is that if i declare an array of television type  to store them the additional attributes(eg int b) of BigTelevision would be lost.

How can i work around this ?

Comment: Why do does a big television need to be represented by a different class? What different behaviour do you need to model for a big television?

Comment: BigTelevision might have discount as an attribute whether as television does not have. Television temp[20] will result in loss of some attribute of BigTelevision if i use it to store Bigtelevision type. is there any way to store the two different types together as a collection

Comment: You can have the `b` member in the `television` class, there's no point in trying to save memory like that. Unless you are going to have several thousands of `television`s.

Comment: I think you should expand on what you are modelling and why. If your television might have a discount attribute it sounds like you are modelling a stock system but I can't imagine why you want to rule out the possibility of ever applying a discount to a television that isn't "big". If I were modelling a stock system I wouldn't even have a `television` class. I might have a generic product class but to a stock system a television might well behave exactly the same as a microwave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to store base class pointers or base class smart pointers ore use a pointer collection like boost:ptr_vector.

```
std::vector<television*> tv;
tv.push_back(new television);
tv.push_back(new BigTelevision);
// don't forget to delete 


// better:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<television>> tv;
tv.push_back(std::unique_ptr<television>(new television));
tv.push_back(std::unique_ptr<television>(new BigTelevision));
```

You can now use different object through a common interface (Polymorphism).

```
class television
{
 public:
    // The interface for all television objects.
    // Each television can calculate its price.
    virtual int Price() const { return price_; }
 private:
    int price_;
};

class BigTelevision
{
 public:
    virtual int Price() const { return television::Price() * discount_; }
 private:
    double discount_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<television>> shoppingCard;
    // add a basic television and a BigTelevision to my shopping card
    shoppingCard.push_back(std::unique_ptr<television>(new television));
    shoppingCard.push_back(std::unique_ptr<television>(new BigTelevision));

    // whats the price for alle the tvs?
    int price = 0;
    for(auto tv = begin(shoppingCard), last = end(shoppingCard); 
        tv != last; ++tv)
        price += (*tv)->Price();

    // or:
    int price = std::accumulate(begin(shoppingCard), end(shoppingCard), 0,
                [](int sum, const std::unique_ptr<television>& tv)
                { return sum + tv->Price()});

}
```

Comment: I think make_unique(..) doesn't need a pointer to a heap allocated object - it creates one and assigns it to the std::unique_ptr<..>. // Edit: Assuming std::make_unique<..>(..)

Comment: @Simon Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `std::make_unique<>()` yet

Comment: You're right. I removed the make_unique call.. it's not (yet) standard.

Answer (score 0):

Will you use a method common to both classes? If so, make that method virtual and create an array of pointers to the base class.